# TDD, PHPUnit doubts

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit, agile

```
class MyClass {

    private $numeric;

    public function MyMethod($numeric)
    {

        if (! is_numeric($numeric)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException
        }

        $this->numeric = $numeric;

    }

}
```

1 - **It is necessary to test whether the class exists?**

The PHPUnit has several methods that run automatically, such as assertPreConditions, setUp, and others. It is necessary within these methods check whether the class exists using the assertTrue and class_exists? Example:

```
protected function assertPreConditions()
{

    $this->assertTrue(class_exists("MyClass"), "The class does not exists.");

}
```

2 - **It is necessary to check if a method exist? If yes, this test should
    be a separate test or within each unit test?**

Suppose we have a method that accepts only numeric type parameters, so we have two tests, one test with the correct parameter and another with incorrect method expecting an exception, right? The correct way to write this method would be ...

This way:

```
public function testIfMyMethodExists()
{
    $this->assertTrue(method_exists($MyInstance, "MyMethod"), "The method does not exists.");
}

/**
* @depends testIfMyMethodExists
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentExcepiton
*/
public function testMyMethodWithAValidArgument()
{
    //[...]
}

/**
* @depends testIfMyMethodExists
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentExcepiton
*/
public function testMyMethodWithAnInvalidArgument()
{
    //[...]
}
```

Or this way?

```
public function testMyMethodWithAValidArgument()
{
    $this->assertTrue(method_exists($MyInstance, "MyMethod"), "The method does not exists.");
}

/**
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentExcepiton
*/
public function testMyMethodWithAnInvalidArgument()
{
    $this->assertTrue(method_exists($MyInstance, "MyMethod"), "The method does not exists.");
    //[...]
}
```

And why?

3 - **What is the real purpose of the @covers and the @coversNothing?**

I was reading a document that Sebastian Bergmann the creator of PHPUnit wrote as good practice we should always write @covers and @coversNothing in the methods and class and add these options in the xml:

```
mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="true"
forceCoversAnnotation="true"
```

and in the whitelist:

```
<whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
    <directory suffix=".php"></directory>
</whitelist>
```

But what is the real need for it?

4 - **What is the correct way to test a constructor that calls another method?**

It seems everything is fine, but not on tests.

Even if I do tests with valid arguments and invalid arguments expecting an exception on the method "MyMethod", that will not happen if I enter an incorrect value in the constructor (The test fails).

And if I test with valid argument, the code coverage does not result in 100%.

```
public function __construct($numeric)
{
    $this->MyMethod($numeric);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write tests for methods that should exist, to test that the code does what it is expected of it.  I also test the InstanceOf() the class (and inherited class definitions) to ensure the object did create what was suppose to be created.  If FOO() extends BAR(), then I test that my object created is an InstanceOf(FOO) and InstanceOf(BAR).  If the class gets changed to inherit from something else, or has the extends removed, my test will once again inform the developer to check the code to ensure this change is desired.  Potentially some inherited functions are being called on FOO, and without the extends from BAR, this code will break.

I write tests on the various code paths that are there to be executed.  Therefore, if I expect that the function should throw an exception when bad data is passed, I write a test for that.  I do this to also help document our source code. The tests show the expected behavior. If someone removes the exception (new functionality to accept a different parameter type) then the test should be updated to show that this is allowed.  Potentially, the change to the parameters could cause a problem elsewhere.  Testing this way ensures that years later, I know that code required this to be a number, and I should definitely re-factor the code carefully if I am changing the parameter types.

Using Test Driven Development (TDD) may cause you to not write the code to throw the exception, as you write a test, then the code to make the test pass.  As such, you might not be testing all the parameters and their types or values, but I try to do this as best as I can to validate reasonable data input to try to avoid the Garbage In/Garbage Out (GIGO) problem.

All these tests also give me a good code coverage metric, as the majority of the code base is tested, and the code does step through all the lines in the class files.  However, testing to this level, and trying to achieve a high code coverage metric, is really a choice for your team to make if this is desired or not.

Comment: It was a good explanation, but I'm still a little confused on your answer. - With "I write tests for methods that should exist, to test that the code does what it is expected of it." you mean that tests whether the methods and class exists (example of the question 1) or not (you don't test if the class or method exists), because the methods and classes MUST exist to be tested?

Comment: Using TDD, you create a method when needed. Therefore, only the methods defined will be called by tests, which I do, to ensure the methods work. I do not explicitly check that the class implements all methods.  However, I also use Reflection to examine Private/Protected methods so the code testing the class can validate that the class works as expected.  I do test the instance type of the class though, even though a new FOO() would fail, I ensure that the returned object is a FOO, and not an OOF. If it is extended from another class, then I ensure it is also of that instance.

Comment: If I have extended the class from another class, then I do check that some common methods exist, and possibly even do a simple test on the parameters, to ensure that they are still in the same order that this class under test is expecting to send them in, since there is not any variable typing, and missed parameters, or altered parameters would not be visible without the testing.

Comment: Can you send me an example of tests that you did that explains what you're talking about? (as the phrase goes, and we programmers love it - talk is cheap, show me the code). Note: pastebin or gist.

Comment: Forget inheritance, I'm testing a class without extension (extends) or implementation of any interface. If you are testing a class like mine, you would check if the class exists and that there are methods like I did in the question? I'll edit the question and add the class to be tested.

Comment: **Updated: Added the class to be tested.**

Comment: **Updated: Added the question 4**

Comment: I would use reflection to see that the internal method set the variables you are expecting to be set.  When testing the constructor, you should also be able to use Reflection to see that the value was set to know that the constructor worked.

Comment: If it is not inherited, then I simply write tests for all the methods, and do not write a test to ensure all methods are there.  You can, but this is doing what the other tests will do anyhow.  I only check for methods if I am inheriting from another class, or using an Interface.

Comment: I did different. - As you can see in the above class, I called a method that probably has not been created, even though the constructor is called the "set" method, the responsibility to set the attribute is the "set" method. The real problem was the issue of Code Coverage, and also to find out if indeed the "set" method was by setting the attribute correctly. So I did a "assertAttributeEquals" and checked the "set" method was executed properly by the construtor. - You can see: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f40dc18a4da3a8394fe8)

Comment: "I only check for methods if I am inheriting from another class, or using an Interface." - Perfect, I have the same point of view.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the code, I would also use Reflection to view the internals of the class to ensure everything is working as expected.  See: https://gist.github.com/Chowarmaan/559b227acf97509d3e34

Comment: Thank you - Soon I'll be posting more questions. Favorite the question.

Comment: If you are happy with any of the answers, you should accept them when you get a chance.  Post more questions into new questions so we can end this really long comments section...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason nor advantage of writing this kind of tests. If the class or the method doesn't exist your tests will fail anyway. So you don't have any profit from writing them.

Maybe the one exception from above (point 1) could be a situation where you always build SUT using PHPUnit mock framework (theoretically a situation where your SUT is a mock with mocked other method you don't need in particular test is possible, but I can't imagine real situation which leads to it).

In my opinion if the test covers flow path which is completely included in another test - this means that the test is redundant and unnecessary.

**edit:**

ad 3. Because you want to know which exactly flow path was invoked by particular unit test. Let's say you have two methods A and B. Method B invokes method A. If you don't have @covers annotation test for method B could generate code coverage for method A, and you can't say if your unit tests for A covers code in 100%.

Comment: Do you think the same about attributes? - Test if the attribute exists with assertObjectHasAttribute or assertClassHasAttribute? In a test "set" method.

Comment: Yes. Pay attention that if you have good unit tests the missing of some object's attribute will cause failed test. If it won't it means that you have missing unit tests or the attribute is not used.

Comment: With this you said that I do always test to check if a attribute exists?

Comment: **Updated: Added question 3.**

Comment: 'covers' is to help with Code Coverage metrics. Also, the @ depends is not normally for the test passing, but to get the results of the previous test to use in this test.  In the manual, you will see an array created with the push, then the pop depends on the push to have the array created from that test, since each test may be run on its own.  @ depends is not an anchor for the previous test passing, but that this function requires the output of the previous test.

Comment: **Updated: Added the class to be tested.**

Comment: Steven Scott - Thanks for talking about @ depends. - I see many people mistakenly using the @ depends. (just like my code above).

Comment: **Updated: Added the question 4.**

Comment: I did the same thing originally.  I thought it tied the tests together and would only run the subsequent tests if the previous ones passed.  Having used PHPUnit for a while now, I can fully understand the @depends use, and the reason to run all the tests regardless.

Comment: I need to understand the right moment to use the @depends, but it is a case of practice.